# What are the advantages of football boots with blades rather than traditional studs?

Tags: football, equipment

Having seen various articles about football managers and coaches who believe bladed football boots to be a safety hazard and knowing that some football teams have banned their use, I was wondering what the supposed advantages of blades are?

Is there an actual advantage to the use of blades rather than studs or is it perhaps more of just a fashion choice by the manufacturer?

Comment: I have never understood the use of blades.  I tried them for soccer, baseball, rugby, and football.  You just feel wobbly on them and then if it rains they stick.  IMO the worst adopted sports gear of all time.  (there have been far worse example that weren't really adopted)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the blades do provide better traction than studs due to a larger surface area, the blades are typically preferred on harder ground because there are more points of contact between the bottom of your foot and the ground which disperses the weight more evenly.  Running a lot on hard ground with studs can cause pain in your underfoot and possibly injure some tendons.

Studs are generally preferred in wet conditions where you will sink into the ground.  In this scenario, the studs will not be supporting your weight (you will sink to the sole of your foot). Also, the lack of surface area is beneficial here because your studs will not gather clumps of mud as easily as the blades would.

Answer (score 2):

I think most of the answers were regarding the long Soft Ground studs as opposed to the conical studs found on something like the Copa Mundials. Both the Copa studs and bladed studs are referred to as Firm Ground studs in most cases. The bladed FG studs provide better traction on the ground whereas the conical studs allow more mobility with quicker realeases. There are hybrids which can be found in both the Nike Tiempos, where you find conical in the front and blades at the back, and on all the new Adidad models, where they have all their studs in a sort of triangular shape.

Answer (score 1):

The little I know on the matter is that the blades are generally assumed/claimed to have better grip when the pitch is too dry/hard for the studs to have a proper grip on.

I have played both with studs and blades, on amateur leagues, and can't really claim to have a remarkable difference. I would argue that the fit of the shoe is much more significant than the type/shape of the "teeth". That being said I also accept that my knowledge on the subject is rather little, and would like to see a more complete answer, with references.

(great question btw, stands to show that not all equipment questions are off-topic/subjective)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer screw ins myself, have tried blades, but to be honest, felt more like I was "sliding" or "skating" forwards, whereas I feel more sure footed with screw ins. The main problem with screw ins for me, is stud pressure pain though, when going from changing room to pitch.